# Black and white theme until hovered

Tags: html, css, web

What CSS would I have to use to make an image black and white until it was hovered over? I would prefer answers to be fully CSS as it will help me learn move about CSS transitions and animation.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:  [w3schools hover](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

You could define that CSS for pretty much any element.  When the mouse is over it, the new style will apply.

Comment: Don't use w3schools. Use MDN instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ Also I wouldn't consider giving someone a link to another website as an answer, rather a comment.

Comment: ok. Sorry about that. Thought that was a reasonable resource. btw:  I would love to have left a comment, rather than an answer, but my reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: No worries. Read about why it isn't a reasonable resource here. http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: w3fools shows nothing about what's wrong, and hasn't been updated since 2011.

Comment: You sure about that? https://github.com/paulirish/w3fools It was updated 2 days ago.... @Sunny